# Fail to print on new line

Tags: java, web

***EDIT: Failed to mention that it is a Java Web program and I think that's why the "\n" wouldn't work, as I was checking my progress in the browser.
It works now, used  `"<br/>"`.***

I'm writing a program that finds all lines from a CSV file, that contain a particular word and then prints those lines, however I cannot get it around to print them on new lines. Here is part of the code:

```
 try {
                in = new Scanner(file);
                while(in.hasNext())
                {
                    String line=in.nextLine();
                    if (line.contains(sb)) {
                        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                        String[] parts = line.split(",");
                        String temp = "Name: "+parts[0]+" Price: "+parts[1] + newLine;
                        System.out.println(temp);
                        System.out.println(" ");
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So, sb stands for the word that we use, which is taken from an input box, the program successfully prints the lines that contain the word, however if its more than 1 line, it prints it on the same line.
Lets say that the word used is ***Howd***, which finds those 2 lines:

Howd,33

Howd Pepper,44

Then, the output should be :

*Name: Howd Price: 33*

*Name: Howd Pepper Price: 44*

However I receive :

**Name: Howd Price: 33 Name: Howd Pepper Price: 44**

and I cannot get it to print on a new line.
I tried adding an empty println,"\n" and line.seperator, is something interfering with the code?
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: The code that you've posted won't produce the output that you've mentioned.

Comment: Did you try System.lineSeparator()?

Comment: ... what IS your system line separator?  Did it get changed somehow?

Comment: Where do you run this code ? Using an IDE? System.out.println should have naturally put a new line by itself at the second turn of the loop. However your example output shows that it did not

Comment: Are you sure this is the code for the output you posted? That code will print each sentence in differents lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I failed to mention that it is a java web program.

But I did manage to do it with
    `+"<br/>"`
to the end of the string, so it works now.

Not sure if I can close the question.

Comment: OK, that was an important detail, yeah.

Comment: At least you have added the "web" tag.